# How do I remove a dependency from an ASP.NET 2.0 .MSI installation?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2005, windows-installer

We've got a VS 2005, .NET 2.0 app, that appears to have a dependency either on ADOMD and/or OLAP.  We don't use either of these in our ASP.NET apps, so I've got to find a way of getting them out of the .MSI that we create.  (We create a .MSI so that we can include Crystal Reports 11 Release 2 as a merge module.)  Is there a way I can remove the dependency upon ADOMD / OLAP, and if so, how?